# How to make multiple instructions in own compiler in Bison?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to implement multiple instructions in my compiler.
To make it simple I will give only small example.
What is working:

```
expr1;
```

What doesn't work:

```
expr1; expr2;
```

And the gramma looks like this:

```
%start expression
%%
expression
    : first ';'
    ;
first
    : first '+' second
    | first '-' second
    | second
    ;
second
    : second '*' number
    | second '/' number
    | number
number
    : NUM_INT
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a rule that matches multiple statements and you can define that using recursion like this:

```
statements
    : statements statement
    | /* empty */
    ;
```

This matches zero or more statements. If you want to require at least one, you should replace the empty case with `statement`.